# Where to Put Common CSS in Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I've been looking at the project structure in the Angular style guide ([angular.io](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#!#-a-id-04-06-a-overall-structural-guidelines)). Everything they recommend seems to make sense, but I'm confused about 1 thing: where would you put common `CSS` in this structure?

By common `CSS`, I'm talking about things like Sass partials that you want to import into multiple other `CSS` files. Or even for the `HTML`, too, if you are using a template language.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using SCSS, then it's a good way to create a `shared/shared.scss` file that contains the common styles.
And import the other components you add a `@import '../shared/shared';` on top of your scss-file to use that common styles.

Answer (score 28):

If you create your project using angular cli you will find a file `styles.css` under `src` folder. Put all your common styles in this file.

`.angular-cli.json` file mentions this file to be bundled as a style

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Scroll down to "App Structure and Angular Modules" in the [Angular 2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html).  The official app structure features `shared` folders (one in the `app` folder) where shared files should go.  Shared CSS files should go in corresponding `shared` folders.

Comment: Would you just make a folder called "styles" or something like that in the shared folder? I'm thinking mostly of styles that aren't necessarily tied to a single component, like common styles for every button in an app.

Comment: Why not `app.component.css` wherever you have `app.component.ts`?

Comment: I'm thinking more for large scale projects that could have a lot of shared CSS going on, where I would want to break the CSS down into relatively small files.

Comment: @tsmith18256 You should probably worry more about breaking your components down into relatively small components.

Answer (score 2):

Create styles folder inside assets folder which holds all shared css files. Now imports these shared css files either in styles.scss file or add directly in angular.json file under styles array.

Shared module is used for only components, pipe, directives and shared ts files